# Azure Pipelines Kubernetes Manifest - must be a directory to be a root

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have a pipeline I am trying to implement the Kubernetes Manifest bake action using a Kustomize render. However when I run this I get the following error:

```
##[error]Error: got file 'kustomization.yaml', but '/home/administrator/BA-L01/_work/80/s/Infrastructure/STARS.API.Web/overlays/devtest/kustomization.yaml' must be a directory to be a root
```

**pipeline.yaml:**

```yaml
- task: KubernetesManifest@0
  displayName: Create Manifest Files
  name: bake
  inputs:
    action: 'bake'
    namespace: ''
    renderType: 'kustomize'
    kustomizationPath: 'Infrastructure/STARS.API.Web/overlays/devtest/kustomization.yaml'
```

**Folder Structure:**

```
STARS.API.Web
└── base
│   │   kustomization.yaml
│   │   service.yaml
│   │   deployment.yaml
│   
└── overlays
    └── devtest
        │   kustomization.yaml
        │   devtest-custom-values.yaml
```

**../base/kustomization.yaml**

```yaml
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

resources:
- service.yaml
- deployment.yaml
```

**../devtest/kustomization.yaml**

```yaml
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

resources:
  - ../../base

patchesStrategicMerge:
  - devtest-custom-values.yaml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says, your `kustomizationPath` must point to the directory where your `kustomization.yaml` is located - not to the `kustomization.yaml` file.

So your **pipeline.yaml** has to be:

```
- task: KubernetesManifest@0
  displayName: Create Manifest Files
  name: bake
  inputs:
    action: 'bake'
    namespace: ''
    renderType: 'kustomize'
    kustomizationPath: 'Infrastructure/STARS.API.Web/overlays/devtest/'
```